# jQuery - toggle click two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is my code (toggle menu):

```
$(function () {
    $('#menu li').click(function () {
        $('#menu li').removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
})
```

Works perfectly. But... If I click on one element and click on it again, the toggle does not close. I would like the menu to close after the second click.

```
$(function () {
    $('#menu li').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
})
```

If I do so, the menu closes after the second click, but... I can expand other menus and the previous one does not close.

How to combine both of these functionalities?

Comment: Can you create a minimal runnable example or add some example html code?

Answer (score 4):

When removing the class from all other `li` element, simply exclude the one you just clicked on with chaining the [.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) function using `this` as a parameter:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#menu li').click(function () {
        $('#menu li').not(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeClass()`/`addClass()` method like below snippet.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#menu li').click(function () {
        $('#menu li').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
})
```

```css
li{
  background: #dddddd;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
  background: #00ff00;
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```